# realistically transporting items across the galaxy

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, space-travel, travel

The year is 2400 and we have a steady alliance with another sapient species that is helping us on our dying planet. The problem? their planet is across the galaxy. How can we realistically (both economically and technologically) travel to their planet and back with their gifts? Their culture is the same as ours but their technology is 400 years more advanced. It's up to you to decide what technology is reasonable for that time. The solution will need to be able to carry a few tons of materials but doesn't need to carry personnel. We can assume that their planets gravity is equal to ours.

Comment: This is Idea Generate + Too Broad, and I'm 99% sure this is a duplicate of a better version of this question already on the site - I'm just too lazy to find it.

Comment: I know but I can't delete it

Comment: "I know but I can't delete it" - How about researching before posting your question next time? Search the site and google extensively before posting the question. Also, don't post questions that are this broad. Localize the questions. See [ask]. This seems to be a recurring problem with most of your questions, btw.

Comment: I know, I working on making them more narrow

Comment: No, you're not. You're still posting questions before they're narrow enough to be posted. Narrow them down first, THEN post them. Use the [Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) to help narrow down your questions before posting on main site.

Comment: I think there is a more fundamental question here. Would it ever be worth it to transport _any_ material across interstellar space? If enough information about the materials to can be transmitted by radio or laser, the aliens could create it, even if they had to make fundamental particles in some kind of cyclotron. It would take less energy and time than transporting tangible materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same physical principles used in establishing and maintaining communication with the aliens. Since our Galaxy is 100k light years across, there is *no way whatsoever* we can communicate using contemporary physics. So just use whatever groundbreaking discoveries (most likely FTL and wormholes) happen in the following 400 or 800 years.